# Will I be able to put Kobo books on my Sony Reader?

Tags: kobo-store, sony

As you may or may not know, Sony's Reader store closed, and they ported everything over to Kobo's services. However, in the past, I have had a lot of trouble buying Kobo books for use on my Sony reader, as they often couldn't be used on the device because of DRM lockouts.

While I managed to find a solution, it did involve stripping the DRM, which is, well, a legally dubious step.

Now that my only purchasing route seems to be Kobo ebooks, have they removed the restriction? Will I be able to use their desktop app or the like to put their books on my device without any problems?

I tried searching for this myself, but I only got results pertaining to the Kobo store switch, but no specifics on how it would or would not work.

Comment: I've been able to use Kobo books on my Sony Reader before. You need to use Adobe Digital Editions. I'm on my way out the door, so can't write a step by step... however I did find this with a quick search: http://www.bookpeople.com/how-download-our-kobo-ebooks-your-sony-ereader

Comment: Did you try a fresh download from Kobo to your Sony?

Comment: @JamesJenkins I don't have anything to install right now and no money to buy more books. That's part of why I am asking - I want to make sure I can do this before I spend more money.

Comment: You should be able to re-download, things you previously purchased at the sony store.  I am assuming you had a sony account, and did not opt-out of the transfer.  In theory, your license for each of the books from Sony is now controlled by Kobo, so you should be able to re-download previous purchases without cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, yes. I was a Kobo customer long before I had a Sony reader. I switched to Sony when my Kobo Touch died.  I was actually happy that the Sony store was killed because it resulted in the Kobo store being put on my Sony reader.

You need the latest firmware update (or at least since the Kobo rollover), and then you will have a "Kobo Bookstore" option on the home screen, and under "Bookshelves", where there used to be "Books", "Collections" and "Evernote" options, there is now an additional "Purchased Content". Select "Purchased Content" and it should show you everything you've ever bought from both the Sony and Kobo stores (and it will handle DRM'd content just fine).